# Cannot allocate a worktable object id because all valid object id values are already in use

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I'm trying to fetch list of id's from a table using java program and i'm checking if those id's are present in another two tables . If they are not present , i'm trying to delete those id's from the first table where i fetched .

I'm running into an exception on 42934th iteration of for loop to check if the account exists in other two tables and this is the exception i'm able to fetch from the logs

`Cannot allocate a worktable object id because all valid object id values are already in use.`

What should i do to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

It looks wired.
The error indicates that you are trying to create new records instead of deleting records.

Check your code, where is trying to create new records, that may be the place error happens.

Comment: I'm not doing any insert . i''m sure , i also have checked the code after your comment

Comment: There may be no code directly insert any record.
But maybe you are using some framework like Hibernate or JPA, which can generate records automatically.

At least, the error message means the limitation reached.
Maybe you can check your database's settings, there should be some configuration item to limit the max record numbers of a table.